# vi editor : How to replace multiple tab by tab-space-tab

Tags: replace, vi

I have a text file which has two TABS consecutively. I need to insert a SPACE between those two TABS.

I am working on vi editor. Can anyone tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use :

```
:%s/\t\t/\t \t/g
```

Do you want to perform multiple substitution on each line?

Answer (score 0):

To globally replace all instances of \t\t with \t \t

:g/\t\t/s//\t \t/g

or to replace the first instance on every line:

:g/\t\t/s//\t \t

Comment: Using `:g` for a global substitution is useless, and moreover your syntax is incorrect.